# Remove physical volumes from logical volume without losing data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filesystems, amazon-ebs, lvm

```
  # pvs output
  PV         VG                 Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/xvdf  server-backups-vol lvm2 a--  1024.00g    0
  /dev/xvdk  server-backups-vol lvm2 a--  1024.00g    0
  /dev/xvdn  server-backups-vol lvm2 a--  1024.00g    0
  /dev/xvdo  server-backups-vol lvm2 a--  1024.00g    0
  /dev/xvdp  server-backups-vol lvm2 a--  1024.00g    0

  # df -h output for the 'server-backups-vol' logical volume
  Size  Used    Avail   Use%
  5.0T  1.8T    3.0T    37%

  # physical volumes containing the 1.8T of data that I want to move
  /dev/xvdn
  /dev/xvdk
```

All of the physical volumes are EBS volumes on AWS, however `xvdn` and `xvdk` are SSD's (gp2) that I want to migrate over to the other disks since they are the cheaper magnetic ones. My plan was to add the other 3 physical volumes to the volume group and resize it to grow the logical volume to full capacity, then I would remove the two SSD's and I had hoped that it would just automagically migrate the data to the remaining disks.. I'm stuck on that last part. [This guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/disk_remove_ex.html#move_exist_ex4) seemed like what I wanted, but my pvs output shows `PFree` is `0`, I'm not sure what the issue is or what the right course of action for correcting it is.

Here are the commands I used to extend the logical volume:

```
vgextend server-backups-vol /dev/xvdf
vgextend server-backups-vol /dev/xvdo
vgextend server-backups-vol /dev/xvdp
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/server-backups-vol/server-backups
resize2fs /dev/server-backups-vol/server-backups
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create a new image of the server. Then fire up a new instance, change the storage type during Launch.

Comment: You can change the storage type of EBS volumes after you've created them? Maybe I'm not understanding

Comment: you can change the storage type when you launch an instance from your AMI

Comment: Those instances are EBS Only, those SSD's are EBS volumes; I think we might be talking about two different things

Comment: I'll explain again. 1) go to instances - created image. 2) go to AMI, select the image created and hit the launch button. 3) At the storage screen you will see all the volumes attached to the AMI with their size and type, change the volume type from SSD to magnetic. Follow the prompts and fire up a new AMI. You dont have to worry about LVs or PVs.